# fullcalendar with time and some custom parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Calendar = function() {

    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function() {
            Calendar.initCalendar();
        },

        initCalendar: function() {

            if (!jQuery().fullCalendar) {
                return;
            }

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            var h = {};

            if (Metronic.isRTL()) {
                if ($('#calendar').parents(".portlet").width() <= 720) {
                    $('#calendar').addClass("mobile");
                    h = {
                        right: 'title',
                        center: '',
                        left: 'month'
                    };
                } else {
                    $('#calendar').removeClass("mobile");
                    h = {
                        right: 'title',
                        center: '',
                        left: 'month'
                    };
                }
            } else {
                if ($('#calendar').parents(".portlet").width() <= 720) {
                    $('#calendar').addClass("mobile");
                    h = {
                        left: 'title',
                        center: '',
                        right: 'month'
                    };
                } else {
                    $('#calendar').removeClass("mobile");
                    h = {
                        left: 'title',
                        center: '',
                        right: 'month'
                    };
                }
            }

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); // destroy the calendar
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
                header: h,
                lang: 'es',
                defaultView: 'month', // change default view with available options from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/ 
                slotMinutes: 15,
                editable: false,
                droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do YY'));
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
        },

                drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    copiedEventObject.className = $(this).attr("data-class");

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                },


                <?php planes_para_calendario_yo(); ?>





            });

        }

    };

}();
</script>
```

My php function looks like:

```
function planes_para_calendario_yo(){
    $db=new Database;
    $q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM planes WHERE coachee='".$_SESSION['duxCoach']."'");
    ##
    $cols=mysql_num_rows($q);
    if($cols>0){
    echo 'events: [{';
    ##
    $i=1;
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
        $ix=$i++;
        if($ix==$cols){
            $divisor='}]';
        }else{
            $divisor='},{';
        }
        $fecha=$r['fecha'];
        $fecha_explode=explode("-",$fecha);
        $fecha_jquery=$fecha_explode[1]-1;
        echo "
        title: 'Sesión ".$r['id']."',
        start: new Date(".$fecha_explode[2].", ".$fecha_jquery.", ".$fecha_explode[0]."),
        backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('red'),
        allDay: false,
        ".$divisor;

    }
    }
}
```

I want to get in the modal some custom parameters like time (retrived from my table as $r['hora'] and id of record $r['id']

How I can get it?
Thanks for help.